# Linear algebra: nilpotent matrix and determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, nilpotence

My linear book had an exercise that demonstrated that a nilpotent matrix A has det(A)=0

$A^k=0$ is the nilpotent condition.
$det(A^k)=(det(A))^k$ and since $det(A^k)=0 \Leftrightarrow det(A)=0$.

My questions:

1. Is the revers relationship also true, i.e. if a determinant=0 is then the matrix nilpotent?
2. Does a nilpotent matrix A decreases the degree of dimensions ,by at least one , with every application on vector x i.e. space to plane to line to point?

Comment: You may consider
$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$
to answer your first question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ponder this a bit more.

Comment: To the second question: not necessarily by one with each application, but it is true that repeatedly applying a nilpotent transformation results in an image that gets smaller with each application

Comment: @BenGrossmann can you therefore say that a nilpotent matrix applied to vectors is space will create the 0 vector in 4 applications or less?

Comment: Why $4$? It is true that an $n \times n$ nilpoent matrix $A$ will satisfy $A^k = 0$ for some value of $k \leq n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann my reasoning behind the number 4 was that a nilpotent 3x3 matrix can at most do 4 applications on a vector in space before it is the zero vector. Space-plane-line-point-zero.

Comment: The point is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your questions can be answered with the theory of Jordan Normal Form:

Every square matrix over an algebraically closed field (e.g. $\Bbb C$) is conjugate to a block-diagonal matrix where each block is of the form:
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
i.e. $\lambda$ on the diagonal, and $1$ on the superdiagonal.

The total number of a specific $\lambda$ on the diagonal of the big matrix is the same as the multiplicity of $(x-\lambda)$ in the characteristic polynomial of the matrix.

---

Since each block is upper triangular, its powers have $\lambda^n$ on the diagonal; in particular:

> It is nilpotent iff all the entries on the diagonal are $0$.

Now the determinant is the product of all the eigenvalues, so:

> The determinant is $0$ iff some diagonal entry is $0$.

Then one can now clearly see that $\det = 0$ does not imply nilpotent, simply by having a matrix with a $0$-block and a nonzero-block, such as the one suggested in the comment, i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, which consists of a $1$-block of size $1$ and a $0$-block of size $1$.

---

As a sidenote, one can see that every nilpotent matrix is conjugate to a matrix with $0$ everywhere except $1$ on some superdiagonal entries.

---

Now if you observe a $0$-block $A$, and if you consider powers of $A$, it's basically shifting the diagonal upward until it disappears, i.e.
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

It so happens that these intermediate forms are all in Reduced Row Echelon Form, so you can read off the rank quite easily: in each block the rank decreases by $1$ each time, until it becomes $0$.

So if $A$ consists of a $0$-block of size 5 and a $0$-block of size 3 and nothing else, then the ranks of the powers of $A$ are $4+2$, $3+1$, $2+0$, $1+0$, and $0+0$.

From this example we can see that generally the rank of $A^n$ keeps decreasing until it reaches $0$, if $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were very thorough and I need to google some terms, but I am a bit wiser for it.

Comment: JNF is really useful